# Determine if argument is numeric

Tags: c#, variables, arguments

In my application i have a method that takes three numbers as arguments. However, the method shall only be able to take numeric values as arguments, and therefore I need to check wether the arguments are numeric or not. How can I do this in an easy and preferably elegant way? Thanks is advance

```
  public Triangle(double a, double b, double c) {
      if ((a != ?) || (b != ?) || (c != ?)){
            throw new ArgumentException("Not a number")
      }   
    sides = new double[] { a, b, c };
  }
```

Comment: You are passing in doubles as arguments, how can they not be numeric?

Comment: How can arguments typed as double in C# be anything but numeric? Are you sure you don't mean that the numbers have to be positive, or that they have to satisfy the triangle inequality?

Comment: Comedy Option: Reference vb.net assembly, and call IsNumeric: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# is strongly typed. Therefore, if you specify that your parameters are numeric, you won't be able to call your method with non-numeric parameters.

Comment: Okey, by that reason I guess I can't throw an exception inside the method if the arguments aren't numeric?

Comment: The compiler won't even allow calling your method with non-numeric arguments, therefore you cannot check for non-numeric arguments, therefore trying to do so would be an exercise in futility.

Comment: It shouldn't compile if the arguments aren't numeric.

Answer (score 1):

In your current code sample, the values are "numeric" by definition that they are typed as `double`. Have a look at the public constants on [`Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx), namely [`NaN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx), [`PositiveInfinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.positiveinfinity.aspx) and [`NegativeInfinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.negativeinfinity.aspx) for the edge cases of double values.

If you want to test whether the values are actually non-numeric based on user input, your arguments should be typed as `string` and you can use [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) (returns `bool`) or [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx) (throws exception) to test if they are numeric.

Comment: +1 for mentioning these boundary cases, as a case could be made that NaN (not a number) is "not numeric".  Note that you cannot compare with NaN directly (all comparisons with NaN return false) and instead have to check this with `double.IsNaN`.

Answer (score 1):

With your prototype:

```
public Triangle(double a, double b, double c)
```

the compiler should throw an error if you attempt to pass anything other than a double to the method. However, if you read the input from the keyboard as, say, string, and you need to check if those strings are doubles, you can use

```
double.TryParse(string, num);
```

Answer (score 0):

As C# is strongly typed, a double is always a numeric value. You don't need to check if it's really a number, as the opposite will never happen.

if you had three `objects` as argument, you would try to cast them or check their type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IsNaN()` (Is Not a Number).

```
if (double.IsNaN(a) || double.IsNaN(b) || double.IsNaN(c))
    throw new ArgumentException(...)
```

Comment: IsNaN cannot be used to evaluate "normal" arguments that just happen to be non-numeric. This will only evaluate to true if you tried some operation of which the result is mathematically undefined, such as dividing by zero. But what the OP wants is to make sure that his method was called with numeric arguments rather than strings, etc.

Comment: @Roy Dictus: I didn't see anything in the original question about testing against strings. Indeed, using strongly typed `double` arguments prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have strings that you have to convert to doubles, you could also have an overload doing the tests and conversions:

```
public Triangle(double a, double b, double c) {  
    sides = new double[] { a, b, c };
}  

public Triangle(string a, string b, string c) {
    double aa, bb, cc;
    if (double.TryParse(a, out aa) && double.TryParse(b, out bb) && double.TryParse(c, out cc)) {  
        sides = new double[] { aa, bb, cc };
    } else {
        throw new ArgumentException("Not a number");
    }
}
```

However, the compiler will never allow you to assign a string to a double variable or method parameter.

Answer (score -1):

try to use AJAX - filtered textbox extender and configure it to accept only Numbers and that solves your problem without any coding.